# Why does this give 1 shift/reduce conflict in yacc / bison

Tags: bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

I want to parse a simple syntax I derived from the /etc/hosts.allow format.
I'm getting a shift/reduce conflict on yacc. Can I ignore the shift/reduce conflict warning or can I amend it somehow?:

```
%token ALLOW
%token DENY
%token COMMENT
%token DEFAULT
%token HOSTUSER
%token PRODUCT

%%
lines: line
    | lines line
line: product_line
    | default_line

product_line: PRODUCT ':' user_host_list ':' allow_deny
            { printf("product line\n"); }
default_line: DEFAULT  ':'  allow_deny
            { printf ("default line\n"); }
allow_deny: ALLOW
            | DENY
user_host_list:
        | HOSTUSER
        | user_host_list HOSTUSER
%%
#include <stdio.h>
extern FILE *yyin;
extern char *yytext;

main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;


   while(yyparse() && !feof(yyin))
    ;
   return 0;
}
```

A sample file looks somthing like this:

```
# comments
# comments

DEFAULT : DENY
<some_product_code> : <list_of_users_hosts> : ALLOW
<some_product_code> : <list_of_users_hosts> : ALLOW
```

(N.B.: the comment-lines # are "eaten up" by the lexer)

I'll add the lexer, too:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

int debug=0;
#define P1(x) if(debug)printf(x)
#define P2(x,y) if(debug)printf(x,y)
#ifdef TEST_LEXER

main()
{
   debug=1;
   while(yylex())
     ;
   return 0;
}
#endif

%}
%option caseless
/*
  "EX-P00V10000-NT-xx"
  "FX-P05E64001-NT-xx"
  "NX-P07E03400-NT-xx"
  "BX-P00B00000-NT-xx"
  "VX-P02E08000-NT-xx"
*/
deny DENY
allow ALLOW
default DEFAULT
product [BCEFKNV][X]-[P][0-9][0-9][EBPV]([0-9]{5,})-NT-xx
name [A-Z_0-9][A-Z_\-0-9\.]*
%%
{product} { P1("PRODUCT! ");return PRODUCT;}
{allow} { P1("ALLOW!\n");return ALLOW; }
{deny} { P1("DENY!\n");return DENY; }
{default}  { P1("DEFAULT!\n");return DEFAULT; }
\*|\\\\{name}|\\\\{name}\\{name}|\\\\{name}\\\*|{name} { P2("HOSTUSER![%s]",yytext); }
#.*(\n|\r\n)  {P1("COMMENT!\n");;}
\n|\r\n|[ ]|\t|, { ; }
.  { P2("[%02hx]",(unsigned char)yytext[0]);return yytext[0]; }

%%
yyerror(char *s) { fprintf(stderr,"Zeile %d: %s[%s]\n",
                                yylineno,s,yytext); fflush(stdout);}
yywrap() { return 1; }
```

And the sample input:

```
# blah blah hello
DEFAULT : DENY
BX-P00B00000-NT-xx : \\host\user \\another\user1 user2 user3 : allow
BX-P00E00003-NT-xx : * : allow
BX-P01B03000-NT-xx : \\host\* : allow # comment here should work, too
BX-P01B03000-NT-xx : \\host\* : allow
# continuation lines too:
BX-P01B03000-NT-xx : user1
                     user2
                     \\host\* : allow
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `user_host_list` definition:

```
user_host_list:
        | HOSTUSER
        | user_host_list HOSTUSER
```

Starts with a `|` that you probably didn't intend. It contains 3 rules. The first rule is empty, so an empty token sequence can reduce to a `user_host_list`. This is the unwanted reduction that causes your conflict.

If you intend to require at least 1 `HOSTUSER`, write it like this:

```
user_host_list:
        HOSTUSER
        | user_host_list HOSTUSER
```

If you intend to allow an empty list, write it like this:

```
user_host_list:
        /* empty */
        | user_host_list HOSTUSER
```

Comment: Thanks. When I do not allow host_user to be empty, I'm getting a syntax error on the first product_line with a [:] as the erroneous token.
I also added the lexer now in my OP

Comment: Your lexer never actually returns `HOSTUSER`.